# MongoDB, finding documents by matching sub elements in an array by several Date conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": ID,
  "seen_at" : [ 
      ISODate("2018-12-27T17:00:00.000Z"), 
      ISODate("2019-01-01T01:00:00.000Z")
  ]
}
```

I try to select document based on a query into the `seen_at` elements:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      "$match": { 
        seen_at: {
            "$gt": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "$lt": ISODate('2019-01-01T00:00:00.001Z')
        }
      }  
    }
  ]
 )
```

I was expecting this query to find only documents that have elements in the `seen_at` that matche both conditions.

But the above query returns the top-above document (among others also not matching both conditions)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) if you have multiple criteria to find from array:

```
db.collection.find({
  seen_at: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "$gt": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "$lt": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.001Z")
    }
  }
})
```

Checkout the results in [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PBufGUMBdz4) for `find`.

If you have to use `Aggregate`, the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator can be used:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $unwind : "$seen_at"
},
{
    "$match": { 
        seen_at: {
            "$gt": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "$lt": ISODate('2019-01-01T00:00:00.001Z')
        }
    }  
},
{
    $group : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "seen_at" : {$push : "$seen_at"}
    }
}
])
```

Checkout the results in [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fraMWltKR3L) for `Aggregate`.